# What exactly does $C^2(D)\cap C(\bar{D})$ denote?

Tags: general-topology

> **Theorem:** (Weak Maximum Principle)
>
> Let $D$ be a bounded domain and let
>   $u(x,y)\in C^2(D)\cap C(\bar{D})$ be a harmonic function in $D$. Then
>   the maximum of $u$ in $\bar{D}$ is achieved on the boundary $\partial
> > D$

Now what exactly does $C^2(D)\cap C(\bar{D})$ denote? What exactly does $D$ denote? Isn't $D$ the union of its boundary and its interior? If so, doesn't $u\in C^2(D)$  tell us, that $u$ is twice continuous differentiable on the interior AND the boundary? Which implies that it is of course also once continuous differentiable - on the boundary and the interior. So that intersection is kind of pointless?

What's the difference here between $D$ and $\bar{D}$? I mean, isn't $\partial D \in D$?

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually "Domain" means open and connected. $C^2(D)\cap C(\bar{D})$ is the set of all functions $u: \bar{D} \to \mathbb R$ which are continuous on $\bar{D}$ and which are  twice continuous differentiable on $D$.

$\bar{D}$ is the closure of $D$.

Comment: ah I actually thought about $D$ being closed.